# C++ SDL cin string inside class causes crash

Tags: c++, sdl

Been having an issue with SDL and my program crashing, its been located as an issue with any `cin >> var` that is used inside a member function.

Here's some code I have that will generate the error -

```
#include "SDL_Wrapper.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Image {
public:
    Image();
    ~Image();
    string getImageName();
protected:
    string imageName;
};

Image::Image() {
}

Image::~Image() {
    //imageName = "";
}

string Image::getImageName() {
    string name;
    cin >> name;
    return name;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Image img;
    img.getImageName();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why this error happens and any way to fix it? It seems very odd that a cin on a string will cause this issue.

Comment: Unless `SDL_Wrapper.h` has some very bad code in it, I cannot see any way this code could possible cause an error except on a severely fragile system.  So, what is `SDL_Wrapper.h`?

Comment: Wait, how are you invoking this program? You're not redirecting input from another source are you?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley the wrapper just links to the SDL library header along with containing some function prototypes inside. I'm just running the program,typing in random text and watching it fail. I had a larger system that was experiencing this issue and my friend found it was the cin causing issues. If I set the string to preset data instead of taking input then it is fine

Comment: 1) What compiler are you using? 2) What options are you passing to the compiler? 3) Do you still get the error if you remove the `#include "SDL_Wrapper.h"`?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm using Visual Studio so whatever compiler comes with that. I'm just running it without debugging, running with debugging causes it too. If I remove "SDL_Wrapper.h" at one point I was told _main was defined with an SDL file. Then if I clean it and rebuild it opens and crashes again. I think it's most definitely SDL causing the issue. I will try a new project and importing SDL through other means

Comment: The issue is caused by the debugger, if I turn the debugger off in the preprocessor commands everything is fine